# run script at tty1, but login at tty6

Tags: tty

I created a live CD that runs a script at tty1. I put the script in /etc/profile.d so it runs at boot. But this way the script also start at the other tty's. I created the script that if the user will abort or press ctrl-c the machine wil reboot, so they cant access shell.

I would like to enable login at tty6 for debug use. How do I do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Scripts in `/etc/profile.d/` will be executed every time someone logs in. It may be the wrong place to put a script that needs to be executed during system boot. You better write a start/stop script or put your script into `/etc/rc.local`:

```
user@host:~# cat /etc/rc.local
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

exit 0
```